# How to initialize a list to a certain value in Python

Tags: python, list

I'd like to get a list where each item is set to a certain value (in my case, 0). I've solved this in my code with the code below, but it feels so messy. Surely there's a better way?

```
maxWidths = map(lambda x: 0, range(0, maxCols))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiply a one-element list by the desired length.

```
maxWidths = [0] * maxCols
```

---

In the above, all elements of the list will be the same objects.
In case you're be creating a list of mutable values (such as dicts or lists), and you need them to be distinct, you can either use `map` as you did in the question, or write an equivalent list comprehension:

```
[[] for dummy in range(100)]
```

Comment: I **knew** there'd be a "python" way! Thanks.

Comment: @nickf Note that the resulting list has `maxCols` references to the same objects. With mutable objects, this leads to quite different (and almost never desriable) semantics.

Comment: To further clarify/illustrate: `[[]] * maxCols` list will actually contain maxCols "references" to the same list.

Comment: @delnan: I was just updating the answer with that. Good catch :)